# How to understand the choice of Krylov subspace orthonormal basis?

Tags: iterative-method, krylov-method, linear-system

This semester, I study the Krylov subspace iterative methods (about Ax=b) using the book **H. A. Van der Vorst. Iterative Krylov Methods for Large Linear Systems,
volume 13. Cambridge University Press, 2003.**
About choice of the basis of the Krylov subspace, I have some doubts about the saying in this book (section 3.3) as follows:

> The obvious basis $r0,Ar_0,...,A^{i-1}r_0$ for i-dimensional Krylov subspace, is not attractive from a numerical point of view, since the vectors $A^jr_0,j=0,...i-1$ point more and more in the direction of the dominant eigenvector for increasing $j$ (the power method!), and hence the basis vectors become dependent in finite precision arithmetic. It does not help to compute this nonorthogonal generic basis first and to orthogonalize it afterwards. The result would be that we have orthogonalized a very ill-conditioned set basis vectors, which is numerically still not an attractive situation.

I have two questions about what the author said (I can not get it what he want to say):

1. **since the vectors $A^jr_0,j=0,...i-1$ point more and more in the direction of the dominant eigenvector for increasing $j$ (the power method!), and hence the basis vectors become dependent in finite precision arithmetic.**
2. **The result would be that we have orthogonalized a very ill-conditioned set basis vectors, which is numerically still not an attractive situation.**

These 2 sentences are what I can not get it, I have known that often we use a Gram-Schmidt to generate an orthonormal basis of Krylov subspace. But I also want to know that why we donot use the obvious basis above the power method?

Furthermore, about the orthonormal basis of the Krylov subspace, I have something to ask. Usually, we use the Gram-Schmidt or modified Gram-Schmidt (MGS) to construct it, but I also know that Householder reflection is more stable, alternatively, we can also use MGS twice (maybe this needs more computational work) to guarantee the orthogonality of the basis. Which way does matlab choose? and why matlab chooses that way in its built-in gmres.m or other built-in functions, like bicg, bicgstab, etc? Which way should we (as a user) choose when we writer a gmres.m function? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt I can explain this better than the author, but I'll give it a shot.

Let's say that $r_0 = \sum \alpha_i x_i$, with $x_i$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

We can then write the vectors in the basis as $A^kr_0 = \sum \lambda_i^k\alpha_i x_i$. If all eigenvalues are distinct, $A^kr_0$ will converge to the eigenvector with the largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue. This is the basis of the power method and what Van der Vorst was referring to.

Because $A^kr_0$ will be close to the eigenvector for large $k$, this also means that $A^kr_0$ and $A^{k+1}r_0$ will be close to eachother. They will still form a basis for the Krylov subspace, but they will be ill-conditioned. (I suggest you read chapter 2 again if you don't understand condition). Working with an ill-conditioned basis is numerically not interesting.

If we then orthogonalise the basis, the basis would have a good condition, but it still is not a good idea. Let's suppose we use a Householder based QR. Since it is backward stable, the numerical result $\hat{Q}\hat{R}$ will be close to $QR$. However, the forward error on $\hat{Q}$ and $\hat{R}$ might still be large and the orthogonal basis that we have computed might not span the correct space.

Edit: Matlab uses Householder, my bad, using 'edit gmres.m' opened up my own implementation. BICG and BICGSTAB are quite different methods, it is a biorthogonalisation scheme that leads to a tridiagonal projection even for non-symmetric matrices. For symmetric matrices, the two subspaces are the same and the orthogonalisation is equivalent to MGS.

When considering what variant to use, I suggest you stick to using MGS. I find it a bit easier to implement. However, if you really become worried about loss of orthogonality for some matrices, you could switch to double MGS or Householder Arnoldi.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 questions. 1, in my matlab, my classmate teaches me that  using `edit gmres` in  command window, I find gmres.m uses **Householder**, and I am sure my matlab is 2018b. Second, as with $r_0=\Sigma \alpha_i x_i$, where $x_i$ are the eigenvectors.  I want to confirm that since matrix $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable, so matrix $A$ may not have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. I mean that if $x_i$ are dependent linearly, can we still  write $r_0=\Sigma \alpha_i x_i$? or It is nothing with the linear independence of the eigenvectors? thanks very much. gmres.m is listed:

Comment: my bad, about the matlab implementation, i was too hasty.

Comment: if the matrix is not diagonalizable, you should be able to apply the jordan canonical form to get to the same results. I haven't checked that myself though.

Answer (score 0):

For Steel's answer. This is my matlab 2018b **gmres.m**: it seems that use Householder reflection. And your matlab 2018b gmres.m uses MGS. 
Are you sure your matlab is 2018b? I am sure mine is matlab 2018b, firmly.[image: gmres.m in matlab2018b]

```matlab
function [x,flag,relres,iter,resvec] = gmres(A,b,restart,tol,maxit,M1,M2,x,varargin)
%GMRES   Generalized Minimum Residual Method.
%   X = GMRES(A,B) attempts to solve the system of linear equations A*X = B
%   for X.  The N-by-N coefficient matrix A must be square and the right
%   hand side column vector B must have length N. This uses the unrestarted
%   method with MIN(N,10) total iterations.
%
%   X = GMRES(AFUN,B) accepts a function handle AFUN instead of the matrix
%   A. AFUN(X) accepts a vector input X and returns the matrix-vector
%   product A*X. In all of the following syntaxes, you can replace A by
%   AFUN.
%
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART) restarts the method every RESTART iterations.
%   If RESTART is N or [] then GMRES uses the unrestarted method as above.
%
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART,TOL) specifies the tolerance of the method.  If
%   TOL is [] then GMRES uses the default, 1e-6.
%
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT) specifies the maximum number of outer
%   iterations. Note: the total number of iterations is RESTART*MAXIT. If
%   MAXIT is [] then GMRES uses the default, MIN(N/RESTART,10). If RESTART
%   is N or [] then the total number of iterations is MAXIT.
%
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M) and
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M1,M2) use preconditioner M or M=M1*M2
%   and effectively solve the system inv(M)*A*X = inv(M)*B for X. If M is
%   [] then a preconditioner is not applied.  M may be a function handle
%   returning M\X.
%
%   X = GMRES(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M1,M2,X0) specifies the first initial
%   guess. If X0 is [] then GMRES uses the default, an all zero vector.
%
%   [X,FLAG] = GMRES(A,B,...) also returns a convergence FLAG:
%    0 GMRES converged to the desired tolerance TOL within MAXIT iterations.
%    1 GMRES iterated MAXIT times but did not converge.
%    2 preconditioner M was ill-conditioned.
%    3 GMRES stagnated (two consecutive iterates were the same).
%
%   [X,FLAG,RELRES] = GMRES(A,B,...) also returns the relative residual
%   NORM(B-A*X)/NORM(B). If FLAG is 0, then RELRES <= TOL. Note with
%   preconditioners M1,M2, the residual is NORM(M2\(M1\(B-A*X))).
%
%   [X,FLAG,RELRES,ITER] = GMRES(A,B,...) also returns both the outer and
%   inner iteration numbers at which X was computed: 0 <= ITER(1) <= MAXIT
%   and 0 <= ITER(2) <= RESTART.
%
%   [X,FLAG,RELRES,ITER,RESVEC] = GMRES(A,B,...) also returns a vector of
%   the residual norms at each inner iteration, including NORM(B-A*X0).
%   Note with preconditioners M1,M2, the residual is NORM(M2\(M1\(B-A*X))).
%
%   Example:
%      n = 21; A = gallery('wilk',n);  b = sum(A,2);
%      tol = 1e-12;  maxit = 15; M = diag([10:-1:1 1 1:10]);
%      x = gmres(A,b,10,tol,maxit,M);
%   Or, use this matrix-vector product function
%      %-----------------------------------------------------------------%
%      function y = afun(x,n)
%      y = [0; x(1:n-1)] + [((n-1)/2:-1:0)'; (1:(n-1)/2)'].*x+[x(2:n); 0];
%      %-----------------------------------------------------------------%
%   and this preconditioner backsolve function
%      %------------------------------------------%
%      function y = mfun(r,n)
%      y = r ./ [((n-1)/2:-1:1)'; 1; (1:(n-1)/2)'];
%      %------------------------------------------%
%   as inputs to GMRES:
%      x1 = gmres(@(x)afun(x,n),b,10,tol,maxit,@(x)mfun(x,n));
%
%   Class support for inputs A,B,M1,M2,X0 and the output of AFUN:
%      float: double
%
%   See also BICG, BICGSTAB, BICGSTABL, CGS, LSQR, MINRES, PCG, QMR, SYMMLQ,
%   TFQMR, ILU, FUNCTION_HANDLE.

%   References
%   H.F. Walker, "Implementation of the GMRES Method Using Householder
%   Transformations", SIAM J. Sci. Comp. Vol 9. No 1. January 1988.

%   Copyright 1984-2017 The MathWorks, Inc.

if (nargin < 2)
    error(message('MATLAB:gmres:NumInputs'));
end

% Determine whether A is a matrix or a function.
[atype,afun,afcnstr] = iterchk(A);
if strcmp(atype,'matrix')
    % Check matrix and right hand side vector inputs have appropriate sizes
    [m,n] = size(A);
    if (m ~= n)
        error(message('MATLAB:gmres:SquareMatrix'));
    end
    if ~isequal(size(b),[m,1])
        error(message('MATLAB:gmres:VectorSize', m));
    end
else
    m = size(b,1);
    n = m;
    if ~iscolumn(b)
        error(message('MATLAB:gmres:Vector'));
    end
end

% Assign default values to unspecified parameters
if (nargin < 3) || isempty(restart) || (restart == n)
    restarted = false;
else
    restarted = true;
    restart = max(restart, 0);
end
if (nargin < 4) || isempty(tol)
    tol = 1e-6;
end
warned = 0;
if tol < eps
    warning(message('MATLAB:gmres:tooSmallTolerance'));
    warned = 1;
    tol = eps;
elseif tol >= 1
    warning(message('MATLAB:gmres:tooBigTolerance'));
    warned = 1;
    tol = 1-eps;
end
if (nargin < 5) || isempty(maxit)
    if restarted
        maxit = min(ceil(n/restart),10);
    else
        maxit = min(n,10);
    end
end
maxit = max(maxit, 0);

if restarted
    outer = maxit;
    if restart > n
        warning(message('MATLAB:gmres:tooManyInnerItsRestart',restart, n));
        restart = n;
    end
    inner = restart;
else
    outer = 1;
    if maxit > n
        warning(message('MATLAB:gmres:tooManyInnerItsMaxit',maxit, n));
        maxit = n;
    end
    inner = maxit;
end

% Check for all zero right hand side vector => all zero solution
n2b = norm(b);                   % Norm of rhs vector, b
if (n2b == 0)                    % if    rhs vector is all zeros
    x = zeros(n,1);              % then  solution is all zeros
    flag = 0;                    % a valid solution has been obtained
    relres = 0;                  % the relative residual is actually 0/0
    iter = [0 0];                % no iterations need be performed
    resvec = 0;                  % resvec(1) = norm(b-A*x) = norm(0)
    if (nargout < 2)
        itermsg('gmres',tol,maxit,0,flag,iter,NaN);
    end
    return
end

if ((nargin >= 6) && ~isempty(M1))
    existM1 = 1;
    [m1type,m1fun,m1fcnstr] = iterchk(M1);
    if strcmp(m1type,'matrix')
        if ~isequal(size(M1),[m,m])
            error(message('MATLAB:gmres:PreConditioner1Size', m));
        end
    end
else
    existM1 = 0;
    m1type = 'matrix';
end

if ((nargin >= 7) && ~isempty(M2))
    existM2 = 1;
    [m2type,m2fun,m2fcnstr] = iterchk(M2);
    if strcmp(m2type,'matrix')
        if ~isequal(size(M2),[m,m])
            error(message('MATLAB:gmres:PreConditioner2Size', m));
        end
    end
else
    existM2 = 0;
    m2type = 'matrix';
end

if ((nargin >= 8) && ~isempty(x))
    if ~isequal(size(x),[n,1])
        error(message('MATLAB:gmres:XoSize', n));
    end
else
    x = zeros(n,1);
end

if ((nargin > 8) && strcmp(atype,'matrix') && ...
        strcmp(m1type,'matrix') && strcmp(m2type,'matrix'))
    error(message('MATLAB:gmres:TooManyInputs'));
end

% Set up for the method
flag = 1;
xmin = x;                        % Iterate which has minimal residual so far
imin = 0;                        % "Outer" iteration at which xmin was computed
jmin = 0;                        % "Inner" iteration at which xmin was computed
tolb = tol * n2b;                % Relative tolerance
evalxm = 0;
stag = 0;
moresteps = 0;
maxmsteps = min([floor(n/50),5,n-maxit]);
maxstagsteps = 3;
minupdated = 0;

x0iszero = (norm(x) == 0);
r = b - iterapp('mtimes',afun,atype,afcnstr,x,varargin{:});
normr = norm(r);                 % Norm of initial residual
if (normr <= tolb)               % Initial guess is a good enough solution
    flag = 0;
    relres = normr / n2b;
    iter = [0 0];
    resvec = normr;
    if (nargout < 2)
        itermsg('gmres',tol,maxit,[0 0],flag,iter,relres);
    end
    return
end
minv_b = b;

if existM1
    r = iterapp('mldivide',m1fun,m1type,m1fcnstr,r,varargin{:});
    if ~x0iszero
        minv_b = iterapp('mldivide',m1fun,m1type,m1fcnstr,b,varargin{:});
    else
        minv_b = r;
    end
    if ~all(isfinite(r)) || ~all(isfinite(minv_b))
        flag = 2;
        x = xmin;
        relres = normr / n2b;
        iter = [0 0];
        resvec = normr;
        return
    end
end

if existM2
    r = iterapp('mldivide',m2fun,m2type,m2fcnstr,r,varargin{:});
    if ~x0iszero
        minv_b = iterapp('mldivide',m2fun,m2type,m2fcnstr,minv_b,varargin{:});
    else
        minv_b = r;
    end
    if ~all(isfinite(r)) || ~all(isfinite(minv_b))
        flag = 2;
        x = xmin;
        relres = normr / n2b;
        iter = [0 0];
        resvec = normr;
        return
    end
end

normr = norm(r);                 % norm of the preconditioned residual
n2minv_b = norm(minv_b);         % norm of the preconditioned rhs
clear minv_b;
tolb = tol * n2minv_b;
if (normr <= tolb)               % Initial guess is a good enough solution
    flag = 0;
    relres = normr / n2minv_b;
    iter = [0 0];
    resvec = n2minv_b;
    if (nargout < 2)
        itermsg('gmres',tol,maxit,[0 0],flag,iter,relres);
    end
    return
end

resvec = zeros(inner*outer+1,1);  % Preallocate vector for norm of residuals
resvec(1) = normr;                % resvec(1) = norm(b-A*x0)
normrmin = normr;                 % Norm of residual from xmin

%  Preallocate J to hold the Given's rotation constants.
J = zeros(2,inner);

U = zeros(n,inner);
R = zeros(inner,inner);
w = zeros(inner+1,1);

for outiter = 1 : outer
    %  Construct u for Householder reflector.
    %  u = r + sign(r(1))*||r||*e1
    u = r;
    normr = norm(r);
    beta = scalarsign(r(1))*normr;
    u(1) = u(1) + beta;
    u = u / norm(u);

    U(:,1) = u;

    %  Apply Householder projection to r.
    %  w = r - 2*u*u'*r;
    w(1) = -beta;

    for initer = 1 : inner
        %  Form P1*P2*P3...Pj*ej.
        %  v = Pj*ej = ej - 2*u*u'*ej
        v = -2*(u(initer)')*u;
        v(initer) = v(initer) + 1;
        %  v = P1*P2*...Pjm1*(Pj*ej)
        for k = (initer-1):-1:1
            Utemp = U(:,k);
            v = v - Utemp*(2*(Utemp'*v));
        end
        %  Explicitly normalize v to reduce the effects of round-off.
        v = v/norm(v);

        %  Apply A to v.
        v = iterapp('mtimes',afun,atype,afcnstr,v,varargin{:});
        %  Apply Preconditioner.
        if existM1
            v = iterapp('mldivide',m1fun,m1type,m1fcnstr,v,varargin{:});
            if ~all(isfinite(v))
                flag = 2;
                break
            end
        end

        if existM2
            v = iterapp('mldivide',m2fun,m2type,m2fcnstr,v,varargin{:});
            if ~all(isfinite(v))
                flag = 2;
                break
            end
        end
        %  Form Pj*Pj-1*...P1*Av.
        for k = 1:initer
            Utemp = U(:,k);
            v = v - Utemp*(2*(Utemp'*v));
        end

        %  Determine Pj+1.
        if (initer ~= length(v))
            %  Construct u for Householder reflector Pj+1.
            u = v;
            u(1:initer) = 0;
            alpha = norm(u);
            if (alpha ~= 0)
                alpha = scalarsign(v(initer+1))*alpha;
                %  u = v(initer+1:end) +
                %        sign(v(initer+1))*||v(initer+1:end)||*e_{initer+1)
                u(initer+1) = u(initer+1) + alpha;
                u = u / norm(u);
                U(:,initer+1) = u;

                %  Apply Pj+1 to v.
                %  v = v - 2*u*(u'*v);
                v(initer+2:end) = 0;
                v(initer+1) = -alpha;
            end
        end

        %  Apply Given's rotations to the newly formed v.
        for colJ = 1:initer-1
            tmpv = v(colJ);
            v(colJ)   = conj(J(1,colJ))*v(colJ) + conj(J(2,colJ))*v(colJ+1);
            v(colJ+1) = -J(2,colJ)*tmpv + J(1,colJ)*v(colJ+1);
        end

        %  Compute Given's rotation Jm.
        if ~(initer==length(v))
            rho = norm(v(initer:initer+1));
            J(:,initer) = v(initer:initer+1)./rho;
            w(initer+1) = -J(2,initer).*w(initer);
            w(initer) = conj(J(1,initer)).*w(initer);
            v(initer) = rho;
            v(initer+1) = 0;
        end

        R(:,initer) = v(1:inner);

        normr = abs(w(initer+1));
        resvec((outiter-1)*inner+initer+1) = normr;
        normr_act = normr;

        if (normr <= tolb || stag >= maxstagsteps || moresteps)
            if evalxm == 0
                ytmp = R(1:initer,1:initer) \ w(1:initer);
                additive = U(:,initer)*(-2*ytmp(initer)*conj(U(initer,initer)));
                additive(initer) = additive(initer) + ytmp(initer);
                for k = initer-1 : -1 : 1
                    additive(k) = additive(k) + ytmp(k);
                    additive = additive - U(:,k)*(2*(U(:,k)'*additive));
                end
                if norm(additive) < eps*norm(x)
                    stag = stag + 1;
                else
                    stag = 0;
                end
                xm = x + additive;
                evalxm = 1;
            elseif evalxm == 1
                addvc = [-(R(1:initer-1,1:initer-1)\R(1:initer-1,initer))*...
                    (w(initer)/R(initer,initer)); w(initer)/R(initer,initer)];
                if norm(addvc) < eps*norm(xm)
                    stag = stag + 1;
                else
                    stag = 0;
                end
                additive = U(:,initer)*(-2*addvc(initer)*conj(U(initer,initer)));
                additive(initer) = additive(initer) + addvc(initer);
                for k = initer-1 : -1 : 1
                    additive(k) = additive(k) + addvc(k);
                    additive = additive - U(:,k)*(2*(U(:,k)'*additive));
                end
                xm = xm + additive;
            end
            r = b - iterapp('mtimes',afun,atype,afcnstr,xm,varargin{:});
            if norm(r) <= tol*n2b
                x = xm;
                flag = 0;
                iter = [outiter, initer];
                break
            end
            minv_r = r;
            if existM1
                minv_r = iterapp('mldivide',m1fun,m1type,m1fcnstr,r,varargin{:});
                if ~all(isfinite(minv_r))
                    flag = 2;
                    break
                end
            end
            if existM2
                minv_r = iterapp('mldivide',m2fun,m2type,m2fcnstr,minv_r,varargin{:});
                if ~all(isfinite(minv_r))
                    flag = 2;
                    break
                end
            end

            normr_act = norm(minv_r);
            resvec((outiter-1)*inner+initer+1) = normr_act;

            if normr_act <= normrmin
                normrmin = normr_act;
                imin = outiter;
                jmin = initer;
                xmin = xm;
                minupdated = 1;
            end

            if normr_act <= tolb
                x = xm;
                flag = 0;
                iter = [outiter, initer];
                break
            else
                if stag >= maxstagsteps && moresteps == 0
                    stag = 0;
                end
                moresteps = moresteps + 1;
                if moresteps >= maxmsteps
                    if ~warned
                        warning(message('MATLAB:gmres:tooSmallTolerance'));
                    end
                    flag = 3;
                    iter = [outiter, initer];
                    break;
                end
            end
        end

        if normr_act <= normrmin
            normrmin = normr_act;
            imin = outiter;
            jmin = initer;
            minupdated = 1;
        end

        if stag >= maxstagsteps
            flag = 3;
            break;
        end
    end         % ends inner loop

    if isempty(initer)
        initer = 0;
    end

    evalxm = 0;

    if flag ~= 0
        if minupdated
            idx = jmin;
        else
            idx = initer;
        end
        if idx > 0 % Allow case inner==0 to flow through
            y = R(1:idx,1:idx) \ w(1:idx);
            additive = U(:,idx)*(-2*y(idx)*conj(U(idx,idx)));
            additive(idx) = additive(idx) + y(idx);
            for k = idx-1 : -1 : 1
                additive(k) = additive(k) + y(k);
                additive = additive - U(:,k)*(2*(U(:,k)'*additive));
            end
            x = x + additive;
        end
        xmin = x;
        r = b - iterapp('mtimes',afun,atype,afcnstr,x,varargin{:});
        minv_r = r;
        if existM1
            minv_r = iterapp('mldivide',m1fun,m1type,m1fcnstr,r,varargin{:});
            if ~all(isfinite(minv_r))
                flag = 2;
                break
            end
        end
        if existM2
            minv_r = iterapp('mldivide',m2fun,m2type,m2fcnstr,minv_r,varargin{:});
            if ~all(isfinite(minv_r))
                flag = 2;
                break
            end
        end
        normr_act = norm(minv_r);
        r = minv_r;
    end

    if normr_act <= normrmin
        xmin = x;
        normrmin = normr_act;
        imin = outiter;
        jmin = initer;
    end

    if flag == 3
        break;
    end
    if normr_act <= tolb
        flag = 0;
        iter = [outiter, initer];
        break;
    end
    minupdated = 0;
end         % ends outer loop

if isempty(outiter)
    outiter = 0;
    initer = 0;
    normr_act = normrmin;
end

% returned solution is that with minimum residual
if flag == 0
    relres = normr_act / n2minv_b;
else
    x = xmin;
    iter = [imin jmin];
    relres = normr_act / n2minv_b;
end

resvec = resvec(1:max(outiter-1,0)*inner+initer+1);
if flag == 2 && initer ~= 0
    resvec(end) = [];
end

% only display a message if the output flag is not used
if nargout < 2
    if restarted
        itermsg(sprintf('gmres(%d)',restart),tol,maxit,[outiter initer],flag,iter,relres);
    else
        itermsg(sprintf('gmres'),tol,maxit,initer,flag,iter(2),relres);
    end
end

function sgn = scalarsign(d)
sgn = sign(d);
if (sgn == 0)
    sgn = 1;
end
```